# T-SQL fastest way to count rows by criteria

Tags: sql, database, performance, t-sql

What is a most fastest way to get count for rows by some criteria?
I have a table: `transactions(id int (PK), userId int, typeId int, dateCreated date, (and about 5-6 additional columns))`
This table has many millions of rows.

Now I need to retrieve the count for records in this table...the criteria for count can be any combination of one to three columns `(userId, typeId, dateCreated)` and dateTime can be "from" and "To".

What should be a query and indexes in order to get the count in fastest way? Is it possible to use only indexes/statistics in order to get the rows count, without reading actual table data?
Does `count(*)` and `count(id)` has performance impact in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: Performing a simple COUNT(*) FROM table can do a much more efficient scan of the clustered index, since it doesn't have to care about any filtering, joining, grouping, etc

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi But simple count of clustered index is not an issue...the problem that query may look like: select count(*) from table where userid = 'someuser' and dateCreated => 'somedate' and dateCreated <= 'somedate', so in this case I need to have non-clustered index on userid and dateCreated. I don't know if it's the only way or I can use non-clustered index directly to get the row count.

Comment: You might try with covering indexes first: `userId, typeId, dateCreated`, `userId, dateCreated`, `typeId, dateCreated`, `dateCreated`; if it proves to be too slow, try aggregated [indexed views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) using the same columns to group by on and `count_big(*)` to pre-count records (although it does not matter if you use * or id, in this case `id` would ask for another column because count_big(*) is necessary in aggregated indexed view). Do not forget to add `noexpand` hint after view name in test query.

Comment: You can also use select count(1) from table (you can use another number or value, does not matter). I tried the 3 forms and all got the same execution plan (for TSQL, MSSQL) select COUNT(*) from sys.sysobjects
select COUNT(id) from sys.sysobjects
select COUNT(1) from sys.sysobjects

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from the indexes, I'm not sure it's 100% accurate but you do not miss the count for more than a few rows.

```
select ob.name,  ix.rowcnt 
from sys.sysindexes ix
join sys.sysobjects ob ON ix.id = ob.id 
where ob.xtype = N'U' and ob.name = N'MyTable'
```

note this way you can get the count for all your tables at once.
obs: note it will return a value for each index in the table